# Use @Grab in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovy-grape

We are trying to use some custom helper functions from a `.jar` library in our Jenkinsfile. To achieve this, we want to use the `@Grab` annotation from groovy/grape. Our Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
@Grab('com.company:jenkins-utils:1.0')
import com.company.jenkinsutils.SomeClass

pipeline {
    ...
}
```

When trying to run the pipeline, we get the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

I already tried specifying `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)`, however to no success. I suppose is has to do with the pipeline scripts running in the sandbox mode? Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Is this scripted or declarative?

Comment: It's scripted, not declarative

Comment: @SimonSchiller Did you find a solution?